# Swift Take a variable in second File ButtonViewController.swift

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

In My project i have two file ViewController.swift and ButtonViewController.swift . In ViewController i have this code

```
var nomeLabel:String!
func goToView(sender: UIButton!) {
// self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToView", sender: self) // I used This for Go to Second View in Another moment
var label: UILabel = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 10, 150, 21);
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "\(self.nomeLabel)"
self.myView.addSubview(label)
})
}
```

and now I want to take the value of the variable self.nomeLabel in the second file ButtonViewController.swift. how can I view this variable in ButtonViewController.swift ?

Comment: Not clear enough. What is 'button.swift'? what is 'nomeLabel'? (I 'guess' a UILabel?). And this line: _"import in the one Label on second file"_. What do you mean 'import in'? What is 'the one', what is 'the second'. Hard to figure what is it you're asking. In you code, there's a `func` that adds a label to some view. There's really not much there.

Comment: I edited my question, no one understood very well before.

Comment: Looks very similar to this other question (answered):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333142/access-variable-in-different-class-swift

Comment: Yes but class Main {   var name:String   init(name:String) {     self.name = name   } } var mainInstance = Main(name:"My Global Class")  I can enter in the ViewController instead of creating the global.swift ?

Comment: I had seen this question but I'm sorry ,I'm not able to develop this with my example

Comment: What is Button.swift? Is it a subclassed UIButton?

Comment: one file in my project I'm sorry I changed the name

Comment: Just declare the variable _outside_ your class, then other classes can access it.