# Swift Access variable in the Class

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

i have this Class in my ViewController.swift for example ...

```
class Person {
internal let name: String
init(name: String) {
self.name = name
}
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

and in my SecondViewController i have

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let person = Person(name: "")
 println(person.name) 
 }
```

How can I assign a value a name from the internal of the view controller class ?

Comment: This is the 3rd time you are posting this question [1st](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980929/swift-take-a-variable-in-second-file-buttonviewcontroller-swift) [2nd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048766/swift-access-controll-example). I realize now that I tried to answer myself on your 2nd one, but you are not giving enough details to figure out what you are really asking

Comment: i want simply assign a value to a name from my Class ViewController .please

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of it:

```
var person = Person(name: "Person Name")
```

I don't know what you are going to do with it - it can be either a local variable in a view controller method, or a view controller property.

Comment: i want assign a value to a name from my Class ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create an instance and it's name property

`var personsName = Person(name: "persons name")`

Comment: no,Perhaps I was not clear I have in my ViewController

Comment: still not clear what you are asking for, as @Antonio said it can be a local variable in a view controller method or property

Comment: i try with var personsName = Person(name: "persons name") but don't go