# Access the same variable before and after value changes in different classes - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables

I've stucked on a simple concept(I guess), basically I have two ViewControllers on Storyboard also I have 2 classes, ViewController and ViewController2:

I Have a Label whit a default value (0), and when I click on button I want to change the value for this variable to 10, and then I click on the button "Show" and I print this variable, I'm successfully changing the Label and printing the new Value.

The real problem is when I want to get the new variable value from another view, even after I change the value if I try to print the variable on second view the variable always return de default value(0)

[image]

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var variable = "0"
@IBOutlet var defaultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label1Label: UILabel!

@IBAction func setValue(sender: AnyObject) {
    setValue()
}


@IBAction func getValue(sender: AnyObject) {
    getValue()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func setValue(){
    variable = "10"
    defaultLabel.text = variable
}

func getValue(){
    print(variable)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

**ViewController2**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label2Label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) {
 print(ViewController().getValue())

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}
```

I've found this post:

[Access variable in different class - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333142/access-variable-in-different-class-swift)

And I really think this is the way that I will find my solution but I really don't understand how to call the variable on ViewController2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
@IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) { 
    print(ViewController().getValue())
}
```

**ViewController()** - this is class constructor and each time you call **ViewController()** it return a new instance/object of **ViewController** class, with default values of course.

If you show **ViewController2** from **ViewController** you can create a property/variable *variable2* like *variable* in **ViewController** and set value before display, but after **ViewController2** is created. If you use segues you can put this code in **ViewController** class:

```
// Put this code in ViewController class
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let viewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2
    if viewController2 != nil {
        // you can't set the value for label at this time 
        // because the viewcontroller and all its UI controls aren't loaded
        // but you can set a non UI variable
        viewController2?.variable2 = self.variable 
    }       
}
```

After that you can put one line of code in viewDidLoad method from ViewController2 class:

```
// Put this code in ViewController2 class
var variable2 = "0"
@IBOutlet var label2Label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label2Label.text = variable2
}
```

Comment: I think I've understood what you proposed, the problem is that I'm working with a container View, so the prepareForsegue is done before any interation, even before I set the new variable value. But I'will explore your logic a little bit more if i can solution my problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Delegates!

Here's an example where `ViewController1` is the delegate for `ViewController2`:

1. Define a protocol:

   ```
   protocol VariableManager {
     func getValue() -> Int
   }
   ```
2. Then, in `ViewController1`, modify the `getValue` method so that `ViewController1` conforms to the protocol:

   ```
   class ViewController1: VariableManager {

     func getValue() -> String {
      return variable
     }

   }
   ```
3. Now define a variable in `ViewController2` named `delegate`:

   ```
   class ViewController2 {
     var delegate: VariableManager?
   }
   ```
4. In your `prepareForSegue` method in `ViewController1` :

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

     if let identifier  = segue.identifier {

       switch identifier {
         case "MySegueIdentifier":
           let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! 'ViewController2'
           destination.delegate = self

       default:
         break
       }

     }

   }
   ```
5. Now in `ViewController2`, change the `show` method:

   ```
   @IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) {
     if let delegate = delegate {
       let variable = delegate.getValue()
       print(variable)
   }
   ```

Delegation is a very common, and very important pattern. I suggest you read up on it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Trying to instantiate another instant of `ViewController1` inside `ViewController2` is **not** good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clarified to me a little bit more, but I'm still having a problem on this line //destination.delegate = self (cannot assign a value of type 'View Controller' to a value of type 'VariableManager?')

Comment: The line you're probably missing is `class ViewController1: VariableManager`. You need to specify that `ViewController` conforms to the `VariableManager` protocol.