# Access a variable from a different class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access a variable from a different class. What am I doing wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var restaurantName = "Test"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()){
            let pop = popView()
            self.view.addSubview(pop)
        }
    }
}
```

here is the class I am trying to access it from:

```
class popView: UIView{

    fileprivate let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:28, weight: .bold)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.text = "TITLE"

        label.text = restaurantName
        return label
    }()
}
```

How can I access the 'restaurantName' variable in the 'popView' class?

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably shouldn't. You should assign the value to a property of the `PopView` instance when you create it

Comment: @Paulw11 how would I do that?

Comment: Declare something like `var textValue: String?` in `PopView` (Note that the class name should start with an uppercase P) and use a `didSet` handler on it to assign it to `titleLabel.text`

Comment: Throwing this out here for future reference: Search your topic before you question it. for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333142/access-variable-in-different-class-swift  that has the same exact question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variable in different class - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333142/access-variable-in-different-class-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to tightly couple the view and the view controller.

You should have a property on your `PopView` to hold the text.  You can then assign a value to this property when you create the `PopView` instance.

```
class PopView: UIView{

    fileprivate let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:28, weight: .bold)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.text = "TITLE"

        label.text = restaurantName
        return label
    }()

    var titleText: String? {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel.text = titleText
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var restaurantName = "Test"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()){
            let pop = popView()
            pop.titleText = restaurantName
            self.view.addSubview(pop)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! is this still bad practice tho?

Comment: No, why would it be?  `PopView` is uncoupled from the view controller; I.e. any view controller can use `PopView` and assign a value to the label.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cant access 'restaurantName' variable in the 'popView' class since the "popupView" class is an instance of "ViewController".

If you want to assign property "restaurantName" to "titleLabel" simply remove the "fileprivate" from property "titleLabel" and add this line before the "addSubview" func.

```
pop.titleLabel.text = restaurantName
```

also change your "popView" class to the following

```
class popView: UIView{

weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:28, weight: .bold)
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
}
```